# Is there a possible way to loop through arrays at a specific range rather than loop through the whole thing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arrayiterator

I'm currently going through array exercises to practice my programming on array iteration. I have an array of string objects inside that look like this.

```
var balling = [
  "Calvin Klein", "Tommy Hilfiger", "FUBU", "Rocca Wear",
  "Calvin Klein", "Tommy Hilfiger", "FUBU", "Rocca Wear"
];
```

Now what I know will work is if I come in and loop through all of them like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < balling.length; i++) {
  balling[i] = console.log(balling[i]);
};
```

and then the whole thing prints out one by one, top to bottom.

What I would rather do is instead of all 8 of the objects inside that array printing out, I want the `for` to specify a specific range of objects inside my array.

What exactly do I have to do for my `for` loop to get the result I want? Is there a way for me to specify how many objects in my array get printed out? Not just one but two, three, and a starting place to start the array and a set range?

Comment: If you just want the second half showing up, you can use something like: for (var i = balling.length/2 , etc etc)

Comment: What if I wanted to go even further than that and specify specifically how many objects I want to show up?

Comment: I dont really understand what you're asking.  How are you determining how many items you want to show up?

Comment: Check the edit but basically what you just said, I'm asking how I can determine how many items are actually showing up in that for loop.

Comment: array.length will give you how many items are in the array.  The declaration of the 'i' variable will determine the starting point of array, in other words, which element will be accessed first, assuming you're increasing the variable as you showed.  Check my answer as well.

Comment: Note, fyi "balling" has nothing to do with apparel. The term was being used before three of the four elements of array existed as publicly available  brands.

Comment: Your starting place is whatever value you assign to `i`, and the non-inclusive ending place will be `i` plus the size of your range, or `balling.length`, whichever is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.min(a,b)` function, that gets the lowest value from `a` or `b`, so if the array length is smaller than the number of entries you want to get as minimal, you will not have a problem:

```
var min_entries = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(balling.length, min_entries); i++) {
  balling[i] = console.log(balling[i]);
};
```

If you want a differente range, you can also use `Array.prototype.slice` method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example

```
var a = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
var sliced = a.slice(1, 3);

console.log(a);      // ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
console.log(sliced); // ['one', 'two']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array having elements reflecting the range of indexes which should be iterated within a `for` loop. Increment the first element of range until second element of range is reached.

```js
var balling = ["Calvin Klein", "Tommy Hilfiger", "FUBU", "Rocca Wear"
              , "Calvin Klein", "Tommy Hilfiger", "FUBU", "Rocca Wear"];

var [from, to] = [2, 5];

for (; from < to; from++) console.log(balling[from]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change declare a var for start and range that will define how many will show eg:

```
var start = 1;
var range = 4;

for (var i = start; i < start + range; i++) {
  balling[i] = console.log(balling[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the 'i' variable in your for loop, that's basically the starting place.

For example, given the array ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and the loop:

```
  for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++ ) {
     console.log(array[i]);
  }
```

that will print out 'b', 'c' and 'd' since the 'i' variable is 1 instead of 0, it won't print the first element. Make sense?